# Sending multiple emails to a list of dictionaries via Mailgun

Tags: python, mailgun

I have a list of dictionaries that I am trying to pass in for the "to" parameter in sending email for Mailgun. Like so:

```
users = [{'User': entry.name.value, 'Email': entry.mail.value, 'Number': entry.telephoneNumber.value,'Days': days_left.days}]
```

also, the days_left is just some math that I did that subtracts when their password was last set - today..

```
days_left = (pwd_expire_date.astimezone(tz=None) - today)
```

My function looks like this:

```
        def send_email():
            for d in notify_users:
                return requests.post(
                    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/MYDOMAIN/messages", auth=("api", "MAILGUN_API_KEY"),
                    data={"from": "IT <mailgun@MYDOMAIN>",
                          "to": d['Email'],
                          "subject": "Password Reminder",
                          "text": f"Hello {d['User']}, you have {d['days']} days left to reset your password. -IT"})
            for d in expired_users:
                return requests.post(
                    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/MYDOMAIN/messages", auth=("api", "MAILGUN_API_KEY"),
                    data={"from": "IT <mailgun@MYDOMAIN>",
                          "to": d['Email'],
                          "subject": "Password Reminder",
                          "text": f"Hello {d['User']}, your password has expired, please change it asap. -IT"})
        send_email()
```

passing in the dictionary in the "to" value seems to only allow the first email in the list, which is not what I want. I must be doing something syntactically wrong. I know that you can pass each individual email into the to field and it will work that way, but is there anyway to pass a list of dictionaries, into the to field? This method worked in Twilio API, for sending multiple sms, but Mailgun doesn't seem to like it.

My script is for sending password reminders when a user is 30,15,3 days from needing to reset their password. the notify_users is anyone who still has a valid password but just needs to be reminded, and the expired_users is for anyone who's password is no longer valid. Each of the emails I want to pass in the name, and how many days are left for that specific user. The syntax for doing that is correct because I have sent test emails and it passed in the right values. I just am failing to pass the list of dictionaries in as the to parameter. If anyone has any insight, it would be very helpful.

This is the expected outcome I am looking to get:

```
each user in the list, for both expired users and users receives a unique email.

'Hello John Apple, you have 15 days left to reset your password. - IT'
'Hello Sandy Cheeks, your password has expired, please change it asap - IT'
```

Comment: Can you build the list into a string before you send the email? You can use things like \n to make a new line.

Comment: Nvm @Joe, I see what you mean! That worked. Thank you so much man. I was stuck on this for a little bit haha.